# Rails 2 + spree (0.11.0): Where is the CheckoutsController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I was given a legacy spree app and I am supposed to edit one of the deeper checkout pages, but I can't get to it on my local because it keeps redirecting me to the shopping cart page with the flash:

`Can't check out, no payment methods are configured for this environment`

My database should be identical to the production database. I can't find `Can't check out, no payment methods are configured for this environment` anywhere in the project. How would I get past this?

I checked the log and it looks like there's a before_filter that's preventing me from going through: `Filter chain halted as [:ensure_payment_methods] rendered_or_redirected.`. However, I can't find this method anywhere in the code. How do I edit controllers that don't exist in my project? How do I find out where they are?

Here's my log:

```
    Processing CheckoutsController#edit (for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-20 10:26:15) [GET]
      Parameters: {"action"=>"edit", "controller"=>"checkouts", "order_id"=>"R838445544"}
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      Order Load (0.6ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."number" = 'R838445544') LIMIT 1
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      Zone Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "zones" WHERE ("zones"."name" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
      Country Load (0.8ms)   SELECT * FROM "countries" 
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."number" = 'R838445544') LIMIT 1
      Checkout Load (0.7ms)   SELECT * FROM "checkouts" WHERE ("checkouts".order_id = 4744) LIMIT 1
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."number" = 'R838445544') LIMIT 1
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      Country Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM "countries" WHERE ("countries"."id" = 214) 
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "countries" WHERE ("countries"."id" = 214) 
      State Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "states" WHERE ("states".country_id = 214) 
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."number" = 'R838445544') LIMIT 1
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."number" = 'R838445544') LIMIT 1
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/boutique/orders/R838445544/checkout/register
    Filter chain halted as [:enforce_registration] rendered_or_redirected.
    Completed in 77ms (DB: 5) | 302 Found [http://localhost/boutique/orders/R838445544/checkout/edit]
      Property Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "properties" WHERE ("properties"."name" = 'brand') LIMIT 1
      AppConfiguration Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "configurations" WHERE ("configurations"."name" = 'Default configuration') AND ( ("configurations"."type" = 'AppConfiguration' ) ) LIMIT 1
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    requiring dependency
    finished requiring.
      SQL (0.1ms)   SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
      SQL (0.1ms)   SET standard_conforming_strings = on
      SQL (0.1ms)   SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'
      User Load IDs For Limited Eager Loading (1.3ms)   SELECT DISTINCT "users".id FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles_users".user_id = "users".id LEFT OUTER JOIN "roles" ON "roles".id = "roles_users".role_id WHERE (roles.name = 'admin') LIMIT 1
      User Load Including Associations (0.8ms)   SELECT "users"."id" AS t0_r0, "users"."email" AS t0_r1, "users"."crypted_password" AS t0_r2, "users"."salt" AS t0_r3, "users"."remember_token" AS t0_r4, "users"."remember_token_expires_at" AS t0_r5, "users"."created_at" AS t0_r6, "users"."updated_at" AS t0_r7, "users"."persistence_token" AS t0_r8, "users"."single_access_token" AS t0_r9, "users"."perishable_token" AS t0_r10, "users"."login_count" AS t0_r11, "users"."failed_login_count" AS t0_r12, "users"."last_request_at" AS t0_r13, "users"."current_login_at" AS t0_r14, "users"."last_login_at" AS t0_r15, "users"."current_login_ip" AS t0_r16, "users"."last_login_ip" AS t0_r17, "users"."login" AS t0_r18, "users"."ship_address_id" AS t0_r19, "users"."bill_address_id" AS t0_r20, "users"."openid_identifier" AS t0_r21, "users"."api_key" AS t0_r22, "users"."creditcard_id" AS t0_r23, "roles"."id" AS t1_r0, "roles"."name" AS t1_r1 FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles_users".user_id = "users".id LEFT OUTER JOIN "roles" ON "roles".id = "roles_users".role_id WHERE (roles.name = 'admin') AND "users".id IN (1) 


    Processing CheckoutsController#register (for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-20 10:26:17) [GET]
      Parameters: {"action"=>"register", "controller"=>"checkouts", "order_id"=>"R838445544"}
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      Order Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."number" = 'R838445544') LIMIT 1
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      Zone Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM "zones" WHERE ("zones"."name" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
      Country Load (0.7ms)   SELECT * FROM "countries" 
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."number" = 'R838445544') LIMIT 1
      Checkout Load (0.6ms)   SELECT * FROM "checkouts" WHERE ("checkouts".order_id = 4744) LIMIT 1
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."number" = 'R838445544') LIMIT 1
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      Country Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM "countries" WHERE ("countries"."id" = 214) 
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "countries" WHERE ("countries"."id" = 214) 
      State Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "states" WHERE ("states".country_id = 214) 
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."number" = 'R838445544') LIMIT 1
      PaymentMethod Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "payment_methods" WHERE ("payment_methods"."deleted_at" IS NULL) 
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/boutique/orders/R838445544/edit
    Filter chain halted as [:ensure_payment_methods] rendered_or_redirected.
    Completed in 83ms (DB: 5) | 302 Found [http://localhost/boutique/orders/R838445544/checkout/register]
      Property Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "properties" WHERE ("properties"."name" = 'brand') LIMIT 1
      AppConfiguration Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "configurations" WHERE ("configurations"."name" = 'Default configuration') AND ( ("configurations"."type" = 'AppConfiguration' ) ) LIMIT 1
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    requiring dependency
    finished requiring.
      SQL (0.1ms)   SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
      SQL (0.1ms)   SET standard_conforming_strings = on
      SQL (0.1ms)   SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'
      User Load IDs For Limited Eager Loading (1.3ms)   SELECT DISTINCT "users".id FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles_users".user_id = "users".id LEFT OUTER JOIN "roles" ON "roles".id = "roles_users".role_id WHERE (roles.name = 'admin') LIMIT 1
      User Load Including Associations (0.8ms)   SELECT "users"."id" AS t0_r0, "users"."email" AS t0_r1, "users"."crypted_password" AS t0_r2, "users"."salt" AS t0_r3, "users"."remember_token" AS t0_r4, "users"."remember_token_expires_at" AS t0_r5, "users"."created_at" AS t0_r6, "users"."updated_at" AS t0_r7, "users"."persistence_token" AS t0_r8, "users"."single_access_token" AS t0_r9, "users"."perishable_token" AS t0_r10, "users"."login_count" AS t0_r11, "users"."failed_login_count" AS t0_r12, "users"."last_request_at" AS t0_r13, "users"."current_login_at" AS t0_r14, "users"."last_login_at" AS t0_r15, "users"."current_login_ip" AS t0_r16, "users"."last_login_ip" AS t0_r17, "users"."login" AS t0_r18, "users"."ship_address_id" AS t0_r19, "users"."bill_address_id" AS t0_r20, "users"."openid_identifier" AS t0_r21, "users"."api_key" AS t0_r22, "users"."creditcard_id" AS t0_r23, "roles"."id" AS t1_r0, "roles"."name" AS t1_r1 FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles_users".user_id = "users".id LEFT OUTER JOIN "roles" ON "roles".id = "roles_users".role_id WHERE (roles.name = 'admin') AND "users".id IN (1) 


    Processing OrdersController#edit (for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-20 10:26:19) [GET]
      Parameters: {"action"=>"edit", "controller"=>"orders", "id"=>"R838445544"}
      Order Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."number" = 'R838445544') LIMIT 1
      Adjustment Load (0.4ms)   SELECT "adjustments".* FROM "adjustments" WHERE ("adjustments".order_id = 4744) ORDER BY position
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      Checkout Load (0.6ms)   SELECT * FROM "checkouts" WHERE ("checkouts".order_id = 4744) LIMIT 1
      SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN
      Order Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."id" = 4744) 
      Shipment Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM "shipments" WHERE ("shipments".order_id = 4744) ORDER BY shipments.id DESC LIMIT 1
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."id" = 4744) 
      SQL (0.1ms)   COMMIT
      SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN
      LineItem Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "line_items" WHERE ("line_items".order_id = 4744) 
      Variant Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "variants" WHERE ("variants"."id" = 179) 
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."id" = 4744) 
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      InventoryUnit Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "inventory_units" WHERE (inventory_units.order_id = 4744) LIMIT 1
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      Shipment Load (1.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "shipments" WHERE ("shipments".order_id = 4744) 
      Charge Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "adjustments" WHERE ("adjustments".order_id = 4744) AND ( ("adjustments"."type" = 'Charge' OR "adjustments"."type" = 'TaxCharge' OR "adjustments"."type" = 'ShippingCharge' ) ) ORDER BY position
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."id" = 4744) 
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."id" = 4744) 
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "shipments" WHERE ("shipments".order_id = 4744) ORDER BY shipments.id DESC LIMIT 1
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      Credit Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM "adjustments" WHERE ("adjustments".order_id = 4744) AND ( ("adjustments"."type" = 'Credit' OR "adjustments"."type" = 'GiftCardCredit' OR "adjustments"."type" = 'CouponCredit' OR "adjustments"."type" = 'ManagersDiscountCredit' OR "adjustments"."type" = 'ReturnAuthorizationCredit' ) ) ORDER BY position
      SQL (0.1ms)   COMMIT
    Rendering template within layouts/spree_application
    Rendering orders/edit
      Image Load (0.6ms)   SELECT * FROM "assets" WHERE ("assets".viewable_id = 179 AND "assets".viewable_type = 'Variant') AND ( ("assets"."type" = 'Image' OR "assets"."type" = 'ProductThumbnail' OR "assets"."type" = 'ProductPageImage' ) ) ORDER BY position
      Product Load (0.7ms)   SELECT * FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."id" = 85) 
      SQL (0.5ms)   SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM "assets" WHERE ("assets".viewable_id = 85 AND "assets".viewable_type = 'Product') AND ( ("assets"."type" = 'Image' OR "assets"."type" = 'ProductThumbnail' OR "assets"."type" = 'ProductPageImage' ) ) 
      Image Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "assets" WHERE ("assets".viewable_id = 85 AND "assets".viewable_type = 'Product') AND ( ("assets"."type" = 'Image' OR "assets"."type" = 'ProductThumbnail' OR "assets"."type" = 'ProductPageImage' ) ) ORDER BY position LIMIT 1
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
      OptionValue Load (0.7ms)   SELECT * FROM "option_values" INNER JOIN "option_values_variants" ON "option_values".id = "option_values_variants".option_value_id WHERE ("option_values_variants".variant_id = 179 ) 
      OptionType Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "option_types" WHERE ("option_types"."id" = 1) 
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Rendered orders/_line_item (195.9ms)
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Rendered orders/_form (201.2ms)
    Rendered orders/_delivery (0.9ms)
      Taxonomy Load (0.6ms)   SELECT * FROM "taxonomies" WHERE (name != 'Featured Products') ORDER BY id
      Taxon Load (0.7ms)   SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons".taxonomy_id IN (1,5,6,7,8) AND (parent_id is null)) 
      Taxon Load (0.3ms)   SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons".parent_id IN (1,33,34,35,37)) ORDER BY "lft"
    Rendered shared/_taxonomies (25.5ms)
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    Rendered shared/_head (2.7ms)
    Rendered shared/_store_menu (0.7ms)
      Order Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."id" = 4744) LIMIT 1
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."id" = 4744) LIMIT 1
      CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "line_items" WHERE ("line_items".order_id = 4744) 
    Rendered shared/_nav_bar (3.5ms)
      Taxon Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons"."permalink" = 'caviar/') LIMIT 1
    **@selected_tab is nil
      Tracker Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "trackers" WHERE ("trackers"."active" = 't' AND "trackers"."environment" = 'development') LIMIT 1
    Rendered shared/_google_analytics (14.7ms)
    Rendered shared/_footer (23.6ms)
    Completed in 400ms (View: 295, DB: 15) | 200 OK [http://localhost/boutique/orders/R838445544/edit]
      Property Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "properties" WHERE ("properties"."name" = 'brand') LIMIT 1
      AppConfiguration Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "configurations" WHERE ("configurations"."name" = 'Default configuration') AND ( ("configurations"."type" = 'AppConfiguration' ) ) LIMIT 1
    Cache hit: Spree::Config ({})
    requiring dependency
    finished requiring.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your `spree_payment_methods` table you will see a column called `environment`. Most likely you don't have any rows with the value of `'development'` in you `environment` column.

Navigate to */admin*

- click **configuration**
- in the right side list click on **payment methods**

Create a payment method and that should solve your problem.

In general you want to clone a local copy of Spree or  whatever Spree expansions you have in your Gemfile, and grep on that to find what you need.